# Voting issues please help

Tags: support, voting

I voted up on a question from frank and when I pressed the up button it voted it down and when I pressed down it went up. Can someone help me? I do not know what to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're trying to upvote something of mine?  I'm not seeing on my rep page about it.  Chances are good you're getting a message of some sort when it reverts it.  Can you post the message?

You currently don't have enough rep to downvote, so it will give you an error message if you try to.  If you press the up arrow after you've already voted on it, you remove your vote.

If you're trying to undo your upvote, though, the post needs to be edited in order for you undo the vote.  Is the up arrow already filled in?

Comment: Thanks frank never mind it works now